# Require.js Backbone modular architecture for r.js

Tags: backbone.js, requirejs, r.js

my_todo_app.html has

1. todo_header.html
2. todo_body.html
3. todo_footer.html

The htmls above are rendered server-side.

todo_header.html creates HeaderView like below(and the two other htmls create their corresponding Backbone Views as well)

```
<div id='header-view'>
  .. other html contents that are rendered in server-side
</div>

require([header_view], function(HeaderView) {
  var headerView = new HeaderView({el: "#header-view");
});
```

Is this bad practice?

I'd like to concatenate javascript files for the todo app using r.js and stuck.
Because r.js concatenates files by looking at the dependancy, and I don't have a file that states todo app depends on HeaderView/BodyView/FooterView.

Should I not separate server-side htmls at all?

Comment: If you render html with backbone you should have client side html templates, havent you?

Comment: @Evgeniy: well, I do have client html templates but I also have server side html templates.

Comment: ok, but i don't clearly how you can include serverside templates into build and what the reason for this?

Comment: @Evgeniy: well, sometimes it's easier to do server-rendering, and it's good to keep the modules separate, so I separate the server templates as well. But on those templates, I sometimes create backbone views.

Comment: do you share same templates on server and client side?

Comment: @Evgeniy: no I dont, they use different template language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just pluck out the javascript require call from nested-template.